# properties of even degree polynomials

Tags: limits

I have recently come across this question that I'm not exactly sure how to even approach.

> I need to show that every polynomial $f(x)$ with an even degree has a property that its limits from both infinity and negative infinity equal.

Sadly, I'm not really sure where to even start...

Comment: I'm having deja vu

Comment: well, that is true. I would concentrate on this: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials of the same degree, the ratio $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ has a (finite) limit, the same at $\pm \infty$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, posted a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Factor out $x^4$. You get $x^4$ times $(a+b/x+\dots+h/x^4)\to a$.

Comment: Could you just elaborate a little, if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Well $x^4\to\infty$.  In fact any even power of $x$ does.  But the other factor goes to $a$.  So, if $a$ is positive, the product goes to $\infty$.